# Доступ к папкам ZIP-архива в Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.6, pytorch

На google colab загружен zip-архив "plates.zip", внутри него есть 2 директории.

Как получить вывод этих двух директорий в виде списка:
['papka_1', 'papka_2']  ?

Мой вариант не срабатывает:

```py
import os
import zipfile

data_root = '../plates.zip/plates/'
print(os.listdir(data_root))
```

Как сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен!

```py
import zipfile

# let's look at the contents of the archive
data_r = zipfile.ZipFile('../plates.zip', 'r')
data_r.printdir()

# extract the contents
data_r.extractall()

# let's look at the working directory
os.getcwd()

# contents of the working directory
print(os.listdir("../наша_папка"))

# contents of our directory
data_root = '../наша_папка/plates/'
print(os.listdir(data_root))
```